# Alphabetical MergeSort Based on a Last Name

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, merge

I need to write a mergeSort function that will merge two files, and sort the lists contained in the files in alphabetical order based on a word in the list. 
The file will look something like this once merged:

```
['Bud', 'Abbott', 51, 92.3]
['Mary', 'Boyd', 52, 91.4]
['Jill', 'Carney', 53, 76.3]
['Jeff', 'Zygna', 50, 82.1]
['Don', 'Adams', 51, 90.4]
['Randy', 'Newman', 50, 41.2]
['Fred', 'Quicksand', 51, 88.8]
['John', 'Ziley', 53, 90.1]
```

The lists are arranged in the order: firstName, lastName, course, grade. What I am attempting to do is sort the lists in alphabetical order based on the last name after merging them. How would I begin to do that?

Comment: Does it actually need to implement the merge sort algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the list of lists:

```
people = [
    ['Bud', 'Abbott', 51, 92.3],
    ['Mary', 'Boyd', 52, 91.4],
    ['Jill', 'Carney', 53, 76.3],
    ['Jeff', 'Zygna', 50, 82.1],
    ['Don', 'Adams', 51, 90.4],
    ['Randy', 'Newman', 50, 41.2],
    ['Fred', 'Quicksand', 51, 88.8],
    ['John', 'Ziley', 53, 90.1]
]
```

You can sort it by surname (i.e. the second element of each list) using the standard `sorted` function and providing a `key` function to extract the surname from the list and use it as a comparison term.

Here's all you need:

```
people_ordered = sorted(people, key = lambda x: x[1])
```

If you want to modify the existing list, you can also use the `.sort()` method instead:

```
people.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: `operator.itemgetter(1)` would be better than a lambda

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already point out how to sort lists of lists based on on a particular index within each element list. If you have to merge by hand, though:

```
target_list = []
counter1, counter2 = 0, 0
while counter1 < len(list1) or counter2 < len(list2):
    if counter1 == len(list1):
        target_list.extend(list2[counter2:])
        break
    if counter2 == len(list2):
        target_list.extend(list1[counter1:])
        break
    if list1[counter1][1] <= list2[counter2][1]:
# the '<=' seems arbitrary, but ensures sort stability in a recursive sort  
# where list1 is the sorted lower half of a previous split
        target_list.append(list1[counter1])
        counter1 += 1
    else:
        target_list.append(list2[counter2])
        counter2 += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell the `sort` function which list item (`key`) it should use for sorting.

```
from pprint import pprint

merged = [
    ['Bud', 'Abbott', 51, 92.3],
    ['Mary', 'Boyd', 52, 91.4],
    ['Jill', 'Carney', 53, 76.3],
    ['Jeff', 'Zygna', 50, 82.1],
    ['Don', 'Adams', 51, 90.4],
    ['Randy', 'Newman', 50, 41.2],
    ['Fred', 'Quicksand', 51, 88.8],
    ['John', 'Ziley', 53, 90.1]
]

merged.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
pprint(merged)
>>> [['Bud', 'Abbott', 51, 92.3],
     ['Don', 'Adams', 51, 90.4],
     ['Mary', 'Boyd', 52, 91.4],
     ['Jill', 'Carney', 53, 76.3],
     ['Randy', 'Newman', 50, 41.2],
     ['Fred', 'Quicksand', 51, 88.8],
     ['John', 'Ziley', 53, 90.1],
     ['Jeff', 'Zygna', 50, 82.1]]
```

Please be aware that `sort()` sorts the list in place, while `sorted()` creates a new list. For more info refer to documentation: [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html).